# My code doesn't work when I change the language beamer

Tags: beamer, tcolorbox, babel-french

My code works great,

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,raster}

\makeatletter

\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{209,23,23}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{255,153,51}
\definecolor{mypurple}{RGB}{102,0,102}
\definecolor{mygrey}{RGB}{200,200,200}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2]{%
    empty,
    coltitle = #1,
    title = #2,
    overlay ={
        \draw[mygrey,line width=1pt]
        (frame.north west)--(frame.north east)--(frame.south east)--(frame.south west)--(frame.north west);
        \draw[#1,line width=1pt]
        ($(frame.north west)!0.33!(frame.south west)$)
        --(frame.north west)
        --($(frame.north west)!0.33!(frame.north east)$);
        \draw[#1,line width=1pt]
        ($(frame.south east)!0.33!(frame.south west)$)
        --(frame.south east)
        --($(frame.south east)!0.33!(frame.north east)$);
    }
}

\tcbset{marktext/.style={%
        overlay={\node[rotate=90,text=black,anchor=north east] at (frame.north west){#1};},
        code={\setbox\z@=\color@hbox#1\color@endbox\tcbdimto\myheight{\wd\z@+3mm}},
        minimum for equal height group=\tcb@ehgid:\myheight,
}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tcbraster}[%
            raster columns=3,
            raster equal height=rows
            ]
            \begin{mybox}{myred}{Title 1}
un peu de texte
            \end{mybox}
            \begin{mybox}{myorange}{Title 2}
un peu de texte
            \end{mybox}
            \begin{mybox}{mypurple}{Title 3}
un peu de texte
            \end{mybox}
        \end{tcbraster}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

but when I change the language to french : \usepackage[french]{babel}, it doesn't work. If someone can help me please

Comment: Exactly what does not work? Do you get an error? If so please vote this error

Comment: When I use \usepackage[french]{babel} instead of  \usepackage[english]{babel}. This is the error that I get : ! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?

Comment: Please load the babel tikz library as well. French babel messes with several chars which confuses tikz

Comment: Is your TeX distribution up to date? Both your examples work fine for me on TexLive 2021.

Comment: how can I load the abbel tikz library, what is the command please

Comment: Yes, !i have texlive 2021, In fact I work with Rsweave, but when I test the code in texstudio , I get the same error

Comment: `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` as one might expect.

Comment: It works thanks a lot

Comment: @Ingmar the OP did not include the line `\usepackage[french]{babel}` in their example

Comment: But I did. And it worked. Either way, this seems to be settled.